# custom authentication using only authorities by username query in spring security

Tags: spring

The following code

```
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    authorities-by-username-query="select USERNAME,ROLE from USERS where USERNAME=?"/>
  </authentication-provider>
```

gives me error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
Jan 14, 2014 10:17:40 PM org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init>
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
```

Comment: jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
     authorities-by-username-query="select USERNAME,ROLE from USERS where USERNAME=?"/>

Comment: Try to use a custom spring security filter. Checkout this blog. http://krams915.blogspot.in/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration-using_26.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend implementing the interface UserDetails, you can check out this project:

https://github.com/pgardunoc/spring-security

The idea is to implement the interface and you will have more control.

Comment: Please answer the below question

Answer (score 0):

> Spring Form .I want to update the request made by customer by changing its status.some of field coming form controller .I want to submit form to controller in order to acess the values

```
h2>Update Request</h2>
>form:form method="POST" action="/my/update.htm" commandName="servicehistory">
table align="center" border="0">

<tr><td>Request Id: </td>
<td><form:input path="sr.ServiceRequestId" value="${sr.serviceRequestId}"></form:input>     < other fields..............
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td></tr>
```

> Controller which access the form value and update the request in database.but it is not happening.GUI displays resource is not available.It was working without Spring Security.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my/update.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)


public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("servicehistory") @Valid ServiceHistories sh1,BindingResult result,ModelMap map)

{

  Redirect it to another page after validating the form
    return new ModelAndView(("redirect:/displaylist.htm"));
}

>Spring Security which implement security after matching url and user role
```

< http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('Technician')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/my/**" access="hasRole('Techincian')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>This is JSp page that is used to assign the compalint to techincian. After hitting submit, it give number format exception

<c:forEach items="${hlist}" var="history" varStatus="i">
<tr>
<td><form:input path="requests[${i.index}].ServiceRequestId" value="${history.serviceRequestId }"></form:input></td>


<td><form:input path="requests[${i.index}].Description"  value="${history.description }"></form:input></td>
<td><form:select multiple="false" path="requests[${i.index}].userto.UserId">
                    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />

             <c:forEach items="${user}" var="u" varStatus="index">                   
                     <form:option label="${u.userName}" value="${u.userId}" />

                   </c:forEach>
                     </form:select>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
<tr><td> <input type="submit" value="Assign Technicians"></td></tr>


>Controller : I am using Autopopulating list to access list coming from above form.But it gives Number format exception because label contains String value and value attribute is an  int. But it is working for another scenario which is identical to this one.

@ModelAttribute("requestForm")
    public RequestForm getRequest()
    {
        RequestForm rf=new RequestForm();
        rf.setRequests(new AutoPopulatingList(ServiceRequests.class));
        return rf;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/assigntech.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String assign(@ModelAttribute("requestForm") RequestForm requestForm,BindingResult result,ModelMap map)
    {
        List<ServiceRequests> sr=(List<ServiceRequests>)requestForm.getRequests();
        System.out.println(sr.size());
        System.out.println(sr.get(0).getUserto().getUserId());

        return "Welcome";
    }
```